# sed - removing zero's - /08/ to /8/

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

What sed command do I need to use to turn /08/ into /8/?

I am looking to get rid of all the excess 0's in my command output.

I have got it down to one pesky extra 0.

```
sed -ie 's/\/0[1-9]\//\/[1-9]\//g' ~/tmp
```

> Outputs: `at 12:27 AM on 5/[1-9]`

```
sed -ie 's/\/0?\//\/?\//g' ~/tmp
```

> Outputs: `at 12:27 AM on 5/08`

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $@ > ~/tmp
sed -ie 's/\/0[1-9]\//\/[1-9]\//g' ~/tmp
AA=`awk '{print $2}' ~/tmp | awk -F : '{print $1":"$2}' | sed 's/^0*//'`
BB=`awk '{print $3}' ~/tmp`
CC=`awk '{print $1}' ~/tmp | awk -F / '{print $1"/"$2}' | sed 's/^0*//'`
DD=`awk '{print $5}' ~/tmp | awk -F : '{print $1":"$2}' | sed 's/^0*//'`
EE=`awk '{print $6}' ~/tmp`
FF=`awk '{print $4}' ~/tmp | awk -F / '{print $1"/"$2}' | sed 's/^0*//'`

if [ $# = 3 ]; then
    echo "at $AA $BB on $CC"

elif [ $# = 6 ] && [ $CC = $FF ]; then
    echo "from $AA $BB to $DD $EE on $FF"

elif [ $# = 6 ]; then
    echo "from $AA $BB on $CC to $DD $EE on $FF"
fi
rm ~/tmp
```

Sample Input Output (alias=dt):

> With current sed command
>
> `dt 05/08/2017 02:27:25 AM`
>
> at 2:27 AM on 5/[1-9]

---

> Without first sed command
>
> `dt 05/08/2017 02:27:25 AM`
>
> at 2:27 AM on 5/08

---

> Solved -- third line replaced with `sed -rie 's/\/0(.?)/\/\1/g' ~/tmp`
>
> `dt 05/08/2017 01:03:56 AM`
>
> Outputs: at 1:03 AM on 5/8

Comment: please provide sample of your input text

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code as text instead of an image

Comment: it keeps replacing the backticks

Comment: Mark up a block of code by selecting it and using the `{}` button. Or manually indent each line by 4 spaces.

Comment: Much appreciated. I have not used this site in a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE**: this is an edited answer to make the solution as general as possible. See the edit history to see what was originally done and see the comments for issues with the previous answer.

The key here is to use grouping via `()` and `-r` for extended regular expressions. Grouping patterns with `()` will allow you to refer to them based on their position in via `\NUMBER` notation. In particular, here's what I came up with:

```
sed -r 's/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)/\1\/\2/g'
```

This reads as so:

- match zero or more characters that are zero
- group together one or more any non-zero character that follows
- then look for slash followed by zero or more characters that are zero
- and group together one or more non-zero characters that follow

In practice this works as so with variable number of zeroes:

```
$ echo "at 12:27 AM on 11/08/2017" | sed -r 's/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)/\1\/\2/g'                                                                         
at 12:27 AM on 11/8/2017
$ echo "at 12:27 AM on 00000011/000008/00002017" | sed -r 's/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)/\1\/\2/g'                                                           
at 12:27 AM on 11/8/00002017
$ echo "at 12:27 AM on 011/08/00002017" | sed -r 's/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)/\1\/\2/g'                                                                    
at 12:27 AM on 11/8/00002017
$ echo "at 12:27 AM on 000000011/0000008/00002017" | sed -r 's/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)/\1\/\2/g'                                                         
at 12:27 AM on 11/8/00002017
```

Notice that this does good enough of a job of retaining whatever comes in the year part if that was required. If we want to get rid of that as well - we can also add a 3rd grouping.

```
$ echo "at 12:27 AM on 005/0025/0002017" | sed -r 's/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)/\1\/\2\/\3/g'                                                    
at 12:27 AM on 5/25/2017
```

This also works fairly well with other chars (which wasn't required but is nice to have):

```
$ echo "at 12:27 AM on 0November/00Fifth/2017" | sed -r 's/0*([^0]+)\/0*([^0]+)/\1\/\2/g'                                                             
at 12:27 AM on November/Fifth/2017
```

Comment: There will only ever be one zero but this worked

Comment: @JoshuaC. Awesome :)  I know it's an overkill to expect more zeroes for date, but just because we can do that - why not , right ?

Comment: I do appropriate learning every little bit more

Comment: Why `0.?(.?)` ? that will remove the first character after the zero... Also since you require the slash in the front, a zero in front of the five would not be removed. `echo "05/08/02017" | sed -r 's/\/0.?(.?)/\/\1/g'` gives `05//02017`, and `echo "05/008/02017" | sed -r 's/\/0.?(.?)/\/\1/g'` gives `05/8/017`

Comment: @ilkkachu yeah, that's wasn't the best approach. I should have used `+` instead to match one or more matches. I'll edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: @ilkkachu  Edited my answer. I've addressed both the variable zeros in day item and retaining the format of the year portion of the date.

Comment: Completely reworked my answer to make it as general as possible. See the edits

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 's/\<00*\([1-9]\)/\1/g' input_data
```

---

Working: This regex looks for an integer [0-9] on whose left is a string of 0s and those zeros are bounded by a word-break `\<`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -ie 's/\/0?\//\/?\//g' ~/tmp
```

First, you can use other characters than the slash as separators for `s///`, that will let you use the slashes without escapes. Second, as  [@Stéphane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) notes, with `-ie` the `e` will be taken as an extension for the backup file, so you'd get a backup file called `tmpe`. I'd change the extension (or remove it), and rewrite as follows:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's,/0?/,/?/,g' ~/tmp
```

Now, it's easier to see the actual pattern this matches: <strike>the strings `//` and `/0/`,</strike> the literal string `/0?/`, which is replaced with `/?/`. (In ERE's the `?` would match zero or one copies of the previous group, so zero or one `0`).

The question mark is not special in the replacement, so it will appear literally. As stated in other answers, you need to use grouping (`(...)` with ERE's or `\(...\)` with BRE's) to capture parts of the pattern, and then `\1` in the replacement to put them back.

So something like this:

```
sed -i.bak -Ee 's,/0*([1-9]),/\1,g' ~/tmp
```

Though note that it will still require the slash in front, so the first zero in `05/08/2017` would not be replaced.

[Rakesh's use of `\<`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/363631/170373) is probably the smart move here, if you want to remove leading zeroes from all words. Then again, changing `12:03:04` to `12:3:4` might not be what you want.

---

That last example of changing `05/08/2017 01:03:56 AM` to `at 1:03 AM on 5/8` could be done with one `sed` command:

```
$ echo '05/08/2017 01:03:56 AM' | 
  sed -Ee 's,0*([0-9]+)/0*([0-9]+)/[0-9]+ 0*([0-9]+):([0-9]+):[0-9]+ ([AP]M),at \3:\4 \5 on \1/\2,'
at 1:03 AM on 5/8
```

I didn't look at what other input formats you wanted to accept.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, whoops, my bad. (I usually use ERE's anyway, and forgot the switch on when checking that pattern). `-ie` was like that in the original Q, added your note on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a regular expression in the replacement text. You mean

```
sed 's/0\([0-9]\)/\1/'
```

Comment: You're missing the `/g` to replace from all matches. also, that would remove the zero from `2017`